# Problem with test automation, WYSYWIG Editor, PHP, REACT

Tags: php, reactjs, testing, automated-tests, behat

I am working on a project, which uses PHP and reacts. My task is to write automated tests in Behat/Mink, but I got stock.

I have a problem with fill react-draft-WYSIWYG component.

I tried to use functions like these:

```
    public function fillField($fieldName, $fieldValue)
{
    $renderedFieldValue = $this->twigRenderStringTemplate($fieldValue, $this->saved);
    $this->fillField($fieldName, $renderedFieldValue);
```

also I tried use js e.g. innerHTML.

WYSIWIG component in code:

```
 <FieldWysiwyg valid={valid} label={t('project:field.companyDescription') + ' *'} name='companyDescription'
                          value={initialValues.companyDescription || ''}/>
```

[Editor in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H03Ov.png)

[WYSIWYG editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXkwd.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to fill this field?

Comment: Check for api of this editor and see if you can create a js script that you can execute with `executeScript`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

When you filled WYSIWYG field you need to 'refresh' DOM. For example clicked 'to left' button on wysywig editor.

```
public function fillWYSIWYGfield($str, $selector)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $n = $page->find('css', $selector);


    $n = $n->find('css', 'span');

    $xpath = $n->getXpath();

    $jsCode = sprintf(
        "
        (function() {
            var eText = document.createTextNode(\"%s\");
            var eSpan = document.createElement(\"span\");
            eSpan.appendChild(eText);
            eSpan.setAttribute('data-text', true);

            var node = document.evaluate(\"%s\", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            var val = node.iterateNext();

            val.textContent = '';
            val.appendChild(eSpan);
        }())
        ",
        $str,
        $xpath
    );
```